# Unable to align bars using jQuery Flot orderBars with errorBars

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to have a multiple series bar chart (using orderBars) where the middle series needs to show errorBars for variable sampling. I can't seem to be able to get the bars to align properly in the grid and I can't figure out how to make it work. Right now up to where I got it done, the left & right bars are aligned properly, but the middle bar jumps up and isn't properly aligned.

[image: Flot bars]

This is my current coding:

```
$(function() {
    var figure0 = [{
        label: "Cost 1", 
        data: [[1,5229.7], [2,4496.8], [3,4307.0], [4,4205.6], [5,3809.7]],
        bars: {
            order: 0
        }
    }, {
        label: "Cost 2", 
        data: [[1,4973.5,500], [2,3380.4,100], [3,3105.7,100], [4,3000.8,100], [5,2939.0,100]],
        points: {
            radius: 0,
            errorbars: "y", 
            yerr: {
                show: true,
                upperCap: "-",
                lowerCap: "-",
                radius: 5,
                color: "black"
            }
        },
        bars: {
            align: "center",
            order: 1
        }
    }, {
        label: "Cost 3", 
        data: [[1,1045.2], [2,881.8], [3,809.0], [4,850.8], [5,771.5]],
        bars: {
            order: 2
        }
    }];

    var formatFigure0 = {
        series: {
            stack: false,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                lineWidth: 1,
                fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1 }] }
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            show: true,
            ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            tickDecimals: 0,
            tickSize: 1,
            axisLabel: "Quintiles"
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
            tickDecimals: 0,
            tickSize: 1000,
            axisLabel: "Dollars (millions)"
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            position: "ne",
            margin: 10,
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: false
        }
    };

    $.plot($("#figure0DIV"), figure0, formatFigure0);
});
```

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I tried to build one but wasn't able to make it work. I'll look more into it if I end up with other questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `errorbars` and `orderBars` plugins don't really work together. You can get them to work, but only easily when the errorbars are for the bars in the center:

[image]

To achieve this I had to make a few changes to your code (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rwx87d1/)):

- Give all three bars the same alignment (when using orderBars you can get away with specifying no alignment at all)
- remove the third values from each datapoint in the second data series because this is interpreted as the offset (jump) for the bar (also remove the error bars here)
- add a new data data series for the errors (here you must have the three values per data point) with bars disabled (this "hack" is also used in the [example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-errorbars/index.html) on the Flot page)

Updated code (replacement for the original second data series):

```
}, {
  label: "Cost 2",
  data: [
    [1, 4973.5], [2, 3380.4], [3, 3105.7], [4, 3000.8], [5, 2939.0]
  ],
  bars: {
    order: 1
  }
}, {
  data: [
    [1, 4973.5, 500], [2, 3380.4, 100], [3, 3105.7, 100], [4, 3000.8, 100], [5, 2939.0, 100]
  ],
  points: {
    radius: 0,
    errorbars: "y",
    yerr: {
      show: true,
      upperCap: "-",
      lowerCap: "-",
      radius: 5,
      color: "black"
    }
  },
  bars: {
    show: false
  },
  lines: {
    show: false
  }
},
```

PS: If you want to get this to work with errorbars for all bars, then you have to calculate the x-offset for the bars yourself and change the x-values on the error data series accordingly.